# using a conditional type in a .cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have a templated class and a type that depends on the template. How can I use this type in my .cpp file?

object.hpp:

```
using pair_d = std::pair<double, double>;
using pair_f = std::pair<float, float>;

template <typename T>
class Object {
    public:
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, float>::value ||
                      std::is_same<T, double>::value, "Type not allowed");

        using pair = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, float>::value,
                     pair_f, pair_d>::type;

        // function using the conditional type
        const pair doSomething(T, T) const;
}
```

object.cpp

```
#include "object.hpp"

template <typename T>
const pair Object<T>::doSomething(T t1, T t2) const {
    // ....
}
```

But the I get:

> error: unknown type name 'pair'

How can I use the type 'pair' in my .cpp file?

Comment: your template should reside in header only, don't split it into h and cpp file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four issues in your snippet:

1. The arguments are named with the same name `(T t, T t)`, make those names different.
2. You have split the template declaration/definition into a cpp and a header file, don't do that.
3. You forgot about a `const` qualifier on a return type in the definition (which is in the declaration).
4. You are missing a `typename` keyword for a dependent name.

Your definition should be:

```
template <typename T>
const typename Object<T>::pair Object<T>::doSomething(T t1, T t2) const {
    // stuff
}
```

or (to avoid a dependent name):

```
template <typename T>
auto Object<T>::doSomething(T t1, T t2) const -> const pair {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: I fixed 1 and 3, thanks. I want to split declaration and definition because the definitions are pretty long. That would not look good in the header file.

Comment: @gartenriese: your solution would not work at all, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to qualify the name if you use it before the `Object<T>` part.

```
template <typename T>
typename Object<T>::pair Object<T>::doSomething(T t, T t) const {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: `typename Object<T>::pair`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this?

```
using pair = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, float>::value,
                     pair_f, pair_d>::type;
```

Why not just:

```
typedef std::pair<T,T> pair;
```

Unless you need two template type arguments. Even if you need two type arguments, use them directly.

I didn't say don't use `static_assert`!

Comment: Do I not have the same problem when using a typedef?

Comment: No. You cannot implement a class template in CPP file (as a translation unit). Templates are compiled using 2 phase compilation process. Second phase would come only on template instantiation, which won't cause CPP file's 2nd phase compilation.